# Why isn't Buddha nature a soul?

Tags: buddhism, souls

I was thinking about 'soul' and whether what is problematic about it for many is less its permanence than its duality (reminded of my friend on the 'kingdom of heaven' "hey look, Jesus is over there!"), be that subject and object or I and thou.

I mean "soul" in the way that it is I believe commonly contrasted with Buddhist anatman, as a "substance" that "supports conscious life", which [Epicurus](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epicurus/)' definition seems to include:

> the soul, on Epicurus' view, also includes, in fact as a key
> ingredient, atoms of a nameless kind of substance, which is
> responsible for sense-perception. Thus it seems that while he thought
> he could explain phenomena such as the heat or warmth of a living
> organism, as well as its movement and rest, by appealing to relatively
> familiar materials and their relatively familiar properties, he did
> feel the need to introduce a mysterious additional kind of substance
> so as to be able to explain sense-perception, apparently on the
> grounds that “sense-perception is found in none of the named elements”
> (L&S 14C).

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ancient-soul/

Comment: Please give a definition of what you mean by "Buddha nature" and what by "soul".

Comment: that's a difficult question. do you mean i should descriminate between different conceptions of both? i am asking in general and in an ecunemical sense @JoWehler

Comment: Please give the definition you are using in your question.

Comment: The various variants of Buddhism embrace anatman: loosely translated as no-self. Buddhism explicitly denies any immortal self or essence.

Comment: is the buddha immortal @Hokon ???

Comment: @prof_post The Buddha, Siddhartha Gautama? No, not in the slightest.

Comment: inteersting thanks! @Hokon

Comment: hey thanks for popping in. you don't think mahaprainirvana was just a trick of the transformation body @Hokon :)
 ?

Comment: @prof_post the Buddhist notion of Nirvana is hard for westerners to grasp, but Siddhartha isn’t who he was to us once he (supposedly) passed “into” Nirvana. Anything we would use to identify him AS Siddhartha is gone.

Comment: that's useful, thanks @Hokon so shakyamuni had died and if there is anything left of him it cannot be identified as him?

Comment: it's not just suicide without religion @Hokon though? i think a lot of my confusion stems from the failure of that early question in buddhist studies

Comment: @prof_post Yeah, impermanence is a key doctrine of Buddhism.

Comment: hmm idgi but there's no use in pushing for some clarity if you don't think it will help :) @Hokon